# how to update redux state again?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to dispatch an action on onPress function -> with navigation action, but the first time I click the screen is rendering as per requirement but the second time I try performing the same function it seems to only navigate to the screen but not call the useEffect or the redux state at all.

I am dispatching the action as follows:

```
 <DrawerItem
                  icon={({color, size}) => (
                    <Icon name="account-outline" color={color} size={size} />
                  )}
                  label="Add a Child"
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('addchild');
                    dispatch(setAddChildRerender(true));
                   
                  }}
                />
```

and my add child screen useEffect looks as follows:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('---states---');
    console.log(date, male, female, iconToggle, name, photo, loading, errmsg);
    if (rerenderScreen === true) {
      setDate();
      image !== null && setImage('');
      setMale('');
      setFemale('');
      setIconToggle('');
      setName('');
      photo && setPhoto(null);
      setLoading(false);
      setErrMsg(null);
    }
  }, []);
```

The first time I click on the drawer item, useeffect is consoling but the second time the useeffect is not consoling at all, could anyone let me know where have I gone wrong?
Any leads would be great, do let me know if there is anything else required for clarity
Thanks in advance

Comment: As you have `[]` in the dependency array of `useEffect`. it is called only once. If you want to call `useEffect` for a certain value change you can add it to the dependency array. Example: If you want to re-render the component to a value change of variable named `name`. add it to the array like `[name]`

Comment: it is still the same, as I told the useeffect is not being called itself!

Comment: As @emkarachchi suggested, your useEffect call doesnt have any dependency array, hence it will be called only once. If you add a dependency in your useEffect, it will be called everytime the dependency item changes.